# how to check exist in a string an element from another string and replace it in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrme

```
     Account    Buy/Sell    Amount  month
1    1001       Sell        52792   2021-Automation-Aug-Dummy.xlsx
5    3001       Buy         85802   2021-Automation-Aug-Dummy.xlsx
8    5601       Buy         10425   2021-Automation-Aug-Dummy.xlsx
11   2001       Buy         12526   2021-Automation-Aug-Dummy.xlsx
14   98071      Sell        90517   2021-Automation-Aug-Dummy.xlsx
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

I want to replace the abv name of the month instead of the long name in the `'month'` column.
For example *'2021-Automation-Aug-Dummy.xlsx'* should be replaced with *'Aug'*.

I have written the following code, but it cannot replace the abv.

```
month_abv = ['Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov']
for inx in test.index:
    if any(abv in month_abv for abv in test.loc[inx,'month']):
        test.loc[inx,'month']= abv
```

But it does not change the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) by joined `month_abv` with `|` for regex or:

```
test['month'] = test['month'].str.extract(f'({"|".join(month_abv)})', expand=False)

print (test)
    Account Buy/Sell  Amount month
1      1001     Sell   52792   Aug
5      3001      Buy   85802   Aug
8      5601      Buy   10425   Aug
11     2001      Buy   12526   Aug
14    98071     Sell   90517   Aug
```

Or if possible get third value aftr split by `-` use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
test['month'] = test['month'].str.split('-').str[2]

print (test)
    Account Buy/Sell  Amount month
1      1001     Sell   52792   Aug
5      3001      Buy   85802   Aug
8      5601      Buy   10425   Aug
11     2001      Buy   12526   Aug
14    98071     Sell   90517   Aug
```

Your solution should be change with lambda function with `next+iter` trick for assign `None` if no match:

```
test['month']= test['month'].apply(lambda x: next(iter(abv for abv in month_abv if abv in x), None))
```